# specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) } = Illegal instruction:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following code in a spec:

```
  describe "using the update action" do
    before { put user_path(user) }    
    specify { response.should redirect_to(login_path) }
  end
```

The result of running the test is:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Not clear what I'm doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you leave out the `do` after the describe statement?

Comment: you miss `do` after "using the update action"

Comment: Thanks @zetetic i wthe problem was missing do with the describe but that doesn't fix the issue. The error is with the 
         `specify { response.should redirect_to(login_path) }`